# Resemblance between $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \sin(2nx)$ and $\cot x$

Tags: trigonometry, summation

Is there a reason why this sum
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \sin(2nx)$$

Has some [resemblence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOs4A.png) to the cotangent function?

Comment: The sum you are asking converges in Abel sense to $\frac{1}{2}\cot \theta$, due to the formula $$ \frac{2r\sin2\theta}{1-2r\cos2\theta+r^2} = 2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^n \sin (2n\theta). $$ This explains why the overall tendency of the partial sums looks like that of cotangent function. But of course, the behavior of envelope is a different story and it seems interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the formula

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sin (2k\theta) = \frac{1}{2}\cot \theta - \frac{1}{2}\frac{\cos(2n+1)\theta}{\sin\theta}, $$

it seems that the upper envelope is given by $ \frac{1}{2}(\cot\theta + |\csc\theta|)$ and likewise the lower envelope is given by $\frac{1}{2}(\cot\theta - |\csc\theta|)$. When $0 < \theta < \pi$, we can simplify them as

$$\frac{1}{2}(\cot\theta + \csc\theta) = \frac{1}{2}\cot\frac{\theta}{2}
\quad\text{and}\quad \frac{1}{2}(\cot\theta - \csc\theta) = - \frac{1}{2}\tan\frac{\theta}{2}. $$